# use an array in column name query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

i want to query column names of a table, put in an array and then use that data in to a table for html,
well is like that

```
<?php
$ser='localhost';
$usr='root';
$pas='password';
$bsd='basedata';
$tab='contact';

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$ser.';dbname='.$bsd.'', $usr, $pas);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SHOW FIELDS FROM $tab ");
    $query->execute();
    echo "<tr>";
    $i=0;

    while ($dat = $query->fetch()) {
        $nombre_columna[$i]=$dat[0];
        echo "<th>".$nombre_columna[$i]."</th>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$ser.';dbname='.$bsd.'', $usr, $pas);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tab");
    $query->execute();
    $j=$i;
    $i=0;
    while ($dat = $query->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($i<$j) {
            echo "<td>".$dat[$nombre_columna[$i]]."</td>";
            $i++;
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $dbh=null;
    ?>
```

so when i run the code it shows onli the first row of the query but no more

Comment: I was trying to edit your post to put in some indentation instead of a big block like that, but you don't have an end tag to your `try` block.

Comment: sorry it's my first and i don't know how to post correctly

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tab` ?

Comment: You can either use a `LIMIT 1` at the end of your select, or a `for` loop.

Comment: @HanletEscaño but the OP is asking why it's limited to 1 row. All that would do is force it to be one row. I'm not sure what that would accomplish.

Comment: SELECT * FROM $tab . ok the result is the entire table that's what i want but when i use $dat[$nombre_columna[$i]] it only shows the full first row of the array correctly but no the second or the thrid or the last

Comment: @Mike seems like I misunderstood the question, although it is not very clear to begin with...

Comment: i find that when i use  the loop `while ($i<$j)` in the `while ($dat = $query->fetch())` flush the entire fetch or something like that _sorry but my english is bad XD_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the output. It *is* looping through every row in the table, but your problem is that the `while ($i<$j)` loop will only work the first time through because you keep incrementing the value of `$i`, so it will never be less than `$j` after the first iteration. You need to reset the value of `$i` on each iteration, not before the loop as you have it.

```
while ($dat = $query->fetch()) {
    $i=0; // <-- This will fix it
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($i<$j) {
        echo "<td>".$dat[$nombre_columna[$i]]."</td>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

If you looked at the source code, I would guess that you would see a bunch of these:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

Comment: really @Mike Mike **you did it!!** thanks a lot it solves my day.

Comment: @zraxas if this answer helped you, please click on the check box to accept it.